# iOS keyboard programatically in Swift using Tasty Imitation Keyboard

Tags: ios, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard

I have been using this :
[Tasty Imitation Keyboard](https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard)

I am having trouble of reading the letters typed by the user.
How can I do that using the above mentioned keyboard ?
Please help.

Comment: is there any `delegate` method available in this `keyboard` ? if not then make own delegate method   and inform when `viewController` when any key is Pressed  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open an issue at the link you provided above. Perhaps the author of the package can help you, although it looks like its been at least 4 months since he's addressed any open issues.

Alternatively, you could try to do it yourself, and then come here ask for assistance with a particular issue. You should provide any error messages you get and the source code that has an issue. At that point we will be able to help. That's as helpful as I can be without seeing any of your code.

Answer (score 0):

UIKIt -> Keyboards & Input -> UITextInputTraits -> keyboardAppearance: UIKeyboard Appearance would be the place where I would start. The link to read up on this is included below. Since you do not have specific code that you are having an issue with, I am not providing any code.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624457-keyboardtype